# Is there a way in es6 to inherit from Error and not have the constructor in the stacktrace?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I tried to write a `HTTPError` class by extending Error:

```
class HTTPError extends Error {
   constructor(codeArg, message){
      let code = codeArg || 500;
      super(message || http.STATUS_CODES[code]); // first line in stack trace
      this.code = code;
   }
}
```

This works mostly fine, but when I `throw` such an error, the line where `super` is called, is the first line in the stack trace (assuming nodejs):

```
> const HTTPError = require('./HTTPError')
undefined
> let e = new HTTPError(418)
undefined
> throw e
Error: I'm a teapot
    at HTTPError (/home/pat/Scripts/js/HTTPError.js:6:6)
    at repl:1:9
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:32:31)
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:96:12)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:31:12)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:308:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:489:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
> e.code
418
```

The first line of the stack trace is in the constructor of `HTTPError`. The interesting one (the one where it was created) is the second `repl:1:9` line. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Error.captureStackTrace`](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_capturestacktrace_targetobject_constructoropt) should be able to fix this, though it's not standard ES6.

```
class HTTPError extends Error {
   constructor(codeArg, message){
      let code = codeArg || 500;
      super(message || http.STATUS_CODES[code]);
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, new.target);
      this.code = code;
   }
}
```

Ultimately I'd call it a bug in the `Error` constructor though, this should not be necessary. There's no standard for stack traces yet, so this is completely implementation-dependent behaviour.

Comment: thanks, `Error.captureStackTrace` fixed my problem. But it should be `HTTPError` as the second argument.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. `new.target` is `HTTPError` when you call `new HTTPError`, but would refer to any subclass automatically

Comment: Oh, thanks `new.target` isn't implemented in the current node stable (after, they've switched to 6.x, it will).

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way is to manually remove that line from the stack.

```
class HTTPError extends Error {
   constructor(codeArg, message){
      let code = codeArg || 500;
      super(message || http.STATUS_CODES[code]); // first line in stack trace
      this.code = code;
      const stack = this.stack.split('\n')
      stack.splice(1, 1)
      this.stack = stack.join('\n')
   }
}
```